# In webhook what is has_custom_certificate: false?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

I have a telegram bot that has an issue because it sends the same message multiple times.

Maybe because the bot doesn't say to telegram that the first operation is correct. It is slow and therefore the telegram sends the message again.

I'm trying to understand the reason but nothing....

Now I noticed that from the `getWebhookInfo` I got:

```
 has_custom_certificate:    false
```

Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must upgrade the SSL certificate
To a self-signed one that uses the same requirements as Telegram
In order to avoid any problems in data transmission

Answer (score 0):

And I remembered that this problem had occurred to me even though everything was correct
Then I knew that the problem was from Telegram, where he restricted the bot from responding to any transmission codes, so I deleted the bot and created a new one and it was running on the same domain that I was using without doing anything.

Answer (score -1):

Install an **ssl** key on your installed domain, this may solve the problem

Comment: Could you elaborate what key, and is it something different than @orochi already mentioned?